# Groupby sequence count and duration of sequence

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have Data frame as shown below.

```
   ID   Status      Date    Cost    Duration
0   1   F       2017-06-22  500     nan
1   1   M       2017-07-22  100     30.00
2   1   P       2017-10-22  100     92.00
3   1   F       2018-06-22  600     243.00
4   1   M       2018-08-22  150     61.00
5   1   P       2018-10-22  120     61.00
6   1   F       2019-03-22  750     151.00
7   2   M       2017-06-29  200     nan
8   2   F       2017-09-29  600     92.00
9   2   F       2018-01-29  500     122.00
10  2   M       2018-03-29  100     59.00
11  2   P       2018-08-29  100     153.00
12  2   M       2018-10-29  100     61.00
13  2   F       2018-12-29  500     61.00
14  3   M       2017-03-20  300     nan
15  3   F       2018-06-20  700     457.00
16  3   P       2018-08-20  100     61.00
17  3   M       2018-10-20  250     61.00
18  3   F       2018-11-20  100     31.00
19  3   P       2018-12-20  100     30.00
20  3   F       2019-03-20  600     90.00
22  4   M       2017-08-10  800     nan
23  4   F       2018-06-10  100     304.00
24  4   P       2018-08-10  120     61.00
25  4   F       2018-10-10  500     61.00
26  4   M       2019-01-10  200     92.00
27  4   F       2019-06-10  600     151.00
```

The data frame is already sorted based on ID and Date

Duration = Number days taken from last Status to current Status for that ID.

I want prepare below Data frame using pandas functions.

```
ID  Nof_F-F  Nof_F-M  Nof_F-P Nof_M-F Nof_M-M  Nof_M-P Nof_P-F Nof_P-M
1   0        2        0       0       0        2       2       0
2   1        0        0       2       0        1       0       1
3   0        0        2       2       0        0       1       1
4   0        1        1       2       0        0       1       0
```

where Nof_F-F = Number of consecutive F-F and so on.

Also I would like to prepare following data frame also

```
    ID  Avg_F-F  Avg_F-M  Avg_F-P Avg_M-F Avg_M-M  Avg_M-P Avg_P-F Avg_P-M
    1   nan      45.5     nan     nan     nan      76.5    197     nan
    2   122      nan      nan     76.5    nan      153     nan     61
    3   nan      nan      45.5    244     nan      nan     90      61
    4   nan      92       61      227.5   nan      nan     61      nan
```

Avg_F-F = Average days for Consecutive F-F and similarly for all other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since already sorted, use `shift` +`where` to create the links. Then `groupby` + `unstack`

```
df['link'] = df.Status.shift().where(df.ID.eq(df.ID.shift())) + '-' + df.Status

df.groupby(['ID', 'link']).agg('size').unstack().fillna(0)
#link  F-F  F-M  F-P  M-F  M-P  P-F  P-M
#ID                                     
#1     0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0
#2     1.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
#3     0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
#4     0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0

df.groupby(['ID', 'link']).Duration.mean().unstack()
#link    F-F   F-M   F-P    M-F    M-P    P-F   P-M
#ID                                                
#1       NaN  45.5   NaN    NaN   76.5  197.0   NaN
#2     122.0  59.0   NaN   76.5  153.0    NaN  61.0
#3       NaN   NaN  45.5  244.0    NaN   90.0  61.0
#4       NaN  92.0  61.0  227.5    NaN   61.0   NaN
```

---

To ensure all links exist in the output use `reindex` after unstacking. Either form the list yourself or use `unique` to get all values that exist.

```
u = df.Status.unique()
cols = [f'{x}-{y}' for x in u for y in u]
#['F-F', 'F-M', 'F-P', 'M-F', 'M-M', 'M-P', 'P-F', 'P-M', 'P-P']

df.groupby(['ID', 'link']).Duration.mean().unstack().reindex(cols, axis=1)

#link    F-F   F-M   F-P    M-F  M-M    M-P    P-F   P-M  P-P
#ID                                                          
#1       NaN  45.5   NaN    NaN  NaN   76.5  197.0   NaN  NaN
#2     122.0  59.0   NaN   76.5  NaN  153.0    NaN  61.0  NaN
#3       NaN   NaN  45.5  244.0  NaN    NaN   90.0  61.0  NaN
#4       NaN  92.0  61.0  227.5  NaN    NaN   61.0   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: M-M and P-P columns are missing. Is it possible to get that too.

Comment: @ALI yes, see the update. You want to `reindex` the columns